# Equivalent definitions for smooth embedding?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, proof-verification, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $N$ and $M$ be smooth manifolds of respective dimensions $n$ and $m$. Let $F:N \to M$ be a smooth map.

**Please verify** my proof of the equivalence of the following 2 definitions.

- From An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu: [Definition 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCxS5.png): Immersion and topological embedding
- From Calculus to Cohomology by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tornehave: [Definition 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPTFo.png): Image is smooth (regular) submanifold (and thus manifold) and diffeomorphism onto image

To prove Definition 1 implies Definition 2:

- Image is smooth submanifold: [Tu Theorem 11.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA3Tv.png)
- Diffeomorphism onto image: Let $i: F(N) \to M$ be inclusion. Then the restriction $\tilde F: N \to F(N)$, which satisfies $F = i \circ \tilde F$ is smooth since $F$ smooth by [Tu Theorem 11.15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEBVE.png). $\tilde F$ is also a diffeomorphism through these steps:

  - Step 1: $\tilde F$, like the original $F$, is an immersion.

    - By this: [$\tilde F$ immersion is equivalent to $F$ immersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299401/tilde-f-immersion-is-equivalent-to-f-immersion)
  - Step 2: $N$ and $F(N)$ have the same dimension.

    - By this: [Do homeomorphic smooth manifolds, like diffeomorphic ones, have the same dimension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298439/do-homeomorphic-smooth-manifolds-like-diffeomorphic-ones-have-the-same-dimensi)
  - Step 3: $\tilde F$ is a local diffeomorphism, i.e. $F$ is a local diffeomorphism onto its image.

    - This follows by Steps 1 and 2 because immersions of manifolds of the same dimension are local diffeomorphisms, as proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298447/for-manifolds-of-the-same-dimension-are-submersions-equivalent-to-immersions).
  - Step 4: $\tilde F$ is a diffeomorphism

    - This follows by Step 3 because any smooth map $G$ of manifolds ([with dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if?noredirect=1&lq=1)) is a diffeomorphism if and only if $G$ is a bijective local diffeomorphism, as proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630351/bijective-local-diffeomorphism-is-a-diffeomorphism) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298579/proof-verification-that-bijective-local-diffeomorphisms-are-diffeomorphisms).

To prove Definition 2 implies Definition 1:

- Homeomorphism onto image: Diffeomorphism onto image implies homeomorphism onto image, i.e. $\tilde F$ diffeomorphism implies $\tilde F$ homeomorphism.
- Immersion: Diffeomorphism onto image implies $\tilde F$ is immersion. Then, $F$ is also an immersion by this again: [$\tilde F$ immersion is equivalent to $F$ immersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299401/tilde-f-immersion-is-equivalent-to-f-immersion)

Comment: $\dim F(N)=\dim N$ simply from the definition: take any point $y\in F(N)$, consider an open neighbourhood $U$ of $F^{-1}(y)$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $F(U)$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @freakish Oh wait I got it. $\dim N = \dim F(N)$ because of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298439/do-homeomorphic-smooth-manifolds-like-diffeomorphic-ones-have-the-same-dimensi) ? Thanks!

Comment: the link seems overly complicated, but yes.

Comment: @freakish Another problem is (1) in Part 2. May you please help?

Comment: What is your definition of submanifold? One simple approach is that if $F(N)$ inherits its differntial structure from $M$ then obviously $D_p(F)=D_p(\tilde F)$ for any point $p\in N$ and so $\tilde F$ is immersion iff $F$ is.

Comment: @freakish Thanks! I actually just decided to ask about it another question. So [this is correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299401/tilde-f-immersion-is-equivalent-to-f-immersion) please?