# $\tilde F$ immersion is equivalent to $F$ immersion

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Related: [Equivalent definitions for smooth embedding?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297560/equivalent-definitions-for-smooth-embedding), [Are manifold subsets submanifolds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297573/are-manifold-subsets-submanifolds)

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu.

Let $N$ and $M$ be smooth manifolds of respective dimensions $n$ and $m$. Let $F:N \to M$ be a smooth map. Let $F(N)$ be a smooth (regular/embedded) submanifold of $M$ and [not simply a manifold subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297573/are-manifold-subsets-submanifolds). Let $i: F(N) \to M$ be inclusion. Let $\tilde F$ be $F$ with restricted range onto its image, i.e. $\tilde F: N \to F(N)$, $F = i \circ \tilde F$. I think the statements below are true.

> C. $\tilde F$ is an immersion $\Rightarrow$ $F$ is an immersion
>
> D. $\tilde F$ is an immersion $\Leftarrow$ $F$ is an immersion

**Question 1.** Are these proofs correct?

For both C and D:

- CD0. [Weaker version of Theorem 11.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spcju.png): Inclusion maps from submanifolds are smooth. (I'm actually not sure if [Theorem 11.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spcju.png) proves this. I ask about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299400/submanifold-implies-inclusion-is-embedding-why-is-the-inclusion-smooth-in-the-f).)
- CD1. $\tilde F$ in the first place is smooth because $F(N)$ is a submanifold and because of (need not be only because of. I [might](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299414/tilde-f-n-to-fn-smooth-implies-image-submanifold) ask about this in another question) [Theorem 11.15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wn3q.png). Therefore, ${\tilde F}_{*,p}$ is defined for each $p \in N$ and thus it makes sense to talk about whether or not $\tilde F$ is an immersion, submersion, etc
- CD2. Similarly, $i$ is smooth because (need not be only because. I [might](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299414/tilde-f-n-to-fn-smooth-implies-image-submanifold) ask about this in another question) $F(N)$ is a submanifold and because of (CD0). Therefore, $i_{*,F(p)}$ is defined for each $F(p) \in F(N)$, and thus it makes sense to discuss whether or not $i$ is an immersion, a submersion, etc.

For C:

- C2. [Weaker version of Theorem 11.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spcju.png): Inclusion maps from submanifolds are (not only smooth but also) immersions (also they are embeddings).
- C3. Because $F(N)$ is a submanifold, $i$ is an immersion by (C2) and (CD2).
- C4. By Chain Rule, (CD1) and (CD2), $F_{*,p} = (i \circ \tilde F)_{*,p} = i_{*,F(p)} \circ \tilde F_{*,p}$
- C5. Therefore, $F_{*,p}$ is injective, by (C4) and by injectivity of ${\tilde F}_{*,p}$ because compositions of injections are injective

For D:

- D2. By Chain Rule, (CD1) and (CD2), $F_{*,p} = (i \circ \tilde F)_{*,p} = i_{*,F(p)} \circ \tilde F_{*,p}$
- D3. $g \circ f$ injective implies $f$ injective, so I think (D2) and injectivity of $F_{*,p}$ give us injectivity of $\tilde F_{*,p}$. (see **Question 2**)

**Question 2.** For (D3), I think we don't care about whether or not $i$ is an immersion. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proofs are correct. Exactly in the same way you can also show the slightly stronger statement:

> Let $F:M\to N$ a smooth map between smoth manifolds und $W$ an embedded submanifold of $N$ such that $f(M)\subseteq W$. Then $F$ is an immersion iff the restriction $\tilde F:M\to W$ is an immersion.

Also your remark concerning (D3) is correct. To say we don't care if $i$ is an immersion means that we can generalize to:

> Let $F:M\to N $ and $G:N\to Q$ be smooth maps between smooth manifolds. If $G\circ F$ is an immersion then $F$ is an immersion.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I assume all [your manifolds have dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if). They could be true if they don't have (uniform) dimensions, but I choose to not think of that now.