# Immersions whose images are actually submanifolds? Or surjective immersions? (I think surjective immersions are local diffeomorphisms)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

**Update**: Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714579/bijective-immersion-is-a-diffeomorphism), I think: **Surjective immersions are (surjective) local diffeomorphisms** because surjective immersions have $\dim {\text{domain}} = \dim{\text{range/image}}$. In particular, surjective immersions are equivalent to surjective local diffeomorphisms. Similarly, **immersions whose images are (regular/embedded) submanifolds of range are local diffeomorphisms onto their images** because $\dim {\text{domain}} = \dim{\text{image}}$, i.e. $n=k$, as below. Please verify that this in fact answers these three questions:

1. [Immersions whose images are actually submanifolds? Or surjective immersions? (I think surjective immersions are local diffeomorphisms)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301261/what-can-we-say-about-immersions-whose-images-are-actually-submanifolds-or-surj)
2. [Are immersions equivalent to local diffeomorphisms onto their images if their images are submanifolds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301259/are-immersions-equivalent-to-local-diffeomorphisms-onto-their-images-if-their-im)
3. [Different proof for immersion is equivalent to local embedding when image is submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301159/immersion-and-local-embedding)

---

Let $N$ and $M$ be smooth manifolds with respective dimensions $n$ and $m$. Let $p \in N$. Let $F: N \to M$ be an immersion at $p$. It can be shown $F$ is a [local embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059110/every-immersion-is-locally-an-embedding) at $p$ (and [conversely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics))).

**Main questions**: If $F$ is an immersion for each $p \in N$ and $F(N)$ is, not only an immersed submanifold of $M$, but actually a (regular/an embedded) $k$-submanifold of $M$, then what can we say (about $F$, $N$, $F(N)$, the restriction $\tilde F: N \to F(N)$ etc)? Or what about if $F$ is additionally surjective (then its image is of course a [submanifold of itself...I guess](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297573/are-manifold-subsets-submanifolds))?

So far I have: (I think these don't use that $F$ is an immersion.)

A. The inclusion $\iota: F(N) \to M$ is a smooth topological embedding and  immersion.

B. The map $\tilde F: N \to F(N)$, $F$ with restricted range that satisfies $F = \iota \circ \tilde F$ is smooth.

**Some guide questions** for the main questions:

C. Does $N$ have the same dimension as $F(N)$, i.e. is $n=k$ ?

D. I haven't thought of any other guide questions.

I'm asking because

1. I find that the assumption that $F(N)$ is a submanifold makes the proof that $F$ is a [local embedding a lot simpler](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301159/immersion-and-local-embedding), assuming the proof is correct.

   - Whether or not the proof is correct, I'm thinking that there's something more to this. Perhaps assuming $F(N)$ submanifold makes $F$ into something where it would be obvious that $F$ is indeed a local embedding, such as because $F$ is actually an embedding (I think $F$ isn't necessarily injective) or a local diffeomorphism (I think immersions are not necessarily local diffeomorphisms).
2. We *might* be able to characterize such immersions as [equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301259/are-immersions-equivalent-to-local-diffeomorphisms-onto-their-images-if-their-im) to [local diffeomorphisms onto their images](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298630/what-is-the-definition-of-local-diffeomorphism-homeomorphism-onto-image).

   - But in this case I think this would mean that surjective immersions are (surjective) local diffeomorphisms. While this would be consistent with both that bijective immersions are diffeomorphisms and that bijective local diffeomorphisms are diffeomorphisms, I wasn't able to find anything about surjective immersions being local diffeomorphisms, but I think this is true if $n=m$ and even if not surjective (and immersions would be local diffeomorphisms onto their images if $n=k$, I guess).
   - In relation to (1), I think (both local diffeomorphisms and) [local diffeomorphisms onto images](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301159/immersion-and-local-embedding) are local embeddings.
   - Since [immersions are equivalent to local embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)), I guess a local embedding with a submanifold image is a local diffeomorphism onto image.
3. For such an $F$, we can say [$F$ is an immersion if and only if $\tilde F$ is an immersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299401/tilde-f-immersion-is-equivalent-to-f-immersion). I suppose we might say this even if $F(N)$ weren't a submanifold or maybe even if not a manifold as long as we have some kind of [smoothness definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299414/tilde-f-n-to-fn-smooth-implies-image-submanifold).